# ExcelJS protect workbook

Tags: node.js, excel, exceljs

I want to create a new excel file that do not allow user open it and delete a worksheet. I 've read the ExcelJS document https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs but only see Sheet Protection and Cell Protection that protect user from delete the data inside a worksheet. But i cann't find a way to protect user from delete a worksheet. That feature is same as "Protect Workbook" that Excel provide.
[image: The Protect Workbook feature]

Can you give me some advices ?

Comment: So set a password to stop opening the workbook.

Comment: Or you can hide sheets - there are two levels of hide...